# BigQuery: add description to routine from variable

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using a script to create a procedure. I have defined a string variable that describes the routine. Now I want to use the declared variable to set the description. While this works for functions it doesn't work for routines. BigQuery tells me that it can not recognize the variable. What am I doing wrong?

```sql
DECLARE doc STRING DEFAULT FORMAT(
"""Doc"""
);

-- This works
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
  `my_dataset.my_fun`()
OPTIONS(description=(doc))
AS ((SELECT 1));

-- This doesn't work. Unrecognized name: doc at ...
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE
  `my_dataset.my_proc`()
OPTIONS(description=(doc))
BEGIN
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

See below routine code. this works for me.

All I have done is added the `create procedure` command part or `execute immediate` and then passed the doc variable value as format string to options

Hope this answers your question

```
BEGIN
DECLARE

doc STRING DEFAULT FORMAT("""DOC""");


EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT ("""
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dataset.options_proc() 
  OPTIONS (description=("%s"))
    BEGIN
      SELECT 1;
    END;
""",doc);

END
```

In the job description you will be able to see the description of the routine procedure.